# validation issue with dropdown list and text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsp

I am having 4 dropdown list boxes those are `year,make,model,sumbodel` and one text box (i.e) mileage, If i select year and mileage and without selecting others, it should show a error message. But it is redirecting to result page. How to stop that redirecting to result page and it has to show the error message

```
if ( typeof ScheduledMaintenance.scheduledMaintenanceForm !== 'function' ) {
    ScheduledMaintenance.scheduledMaintenanceForm = {
        submitScheduledMaintenanceForm : function () {
            var acesVehicleId = this.sanitizeScheduledMaintenanceURLNumber($("#acesVehicleIdHidden").val());
            var year = this.sanitizeScheduledMaintenanceURLNumber($("#year option:selected").text());
            var make = this.sanitizeScheduledMaintenanceURLString($("#make option:selected").text());
            var model = this.sanitizeScheduledMaintenanceURLString($("#model option:selected").text());
            var submodel = this.sanitizeScheduledMaintenanceURLString($("#submodel option:selected").text());
            var mileage = this.sanitizeScheduledMaintenanceURLNumber($("#mileage").val());

            var scheduledMaintenanceURL = "/vehicle-scheduled-maintenance/"+acesVehicleId;
            if (mileage != null && mileage.length > 0) {
                scheduledMaintenanceURL += "/"+mileage;
            }
            scheduledMaintenanceURL += "/"+year+"-"+make+"-"+model;
            if (submodel != null && submodel.length > 0 && submodel != "Default") {
                // some submodels consist of nothing but special characters, so don't use those
                scheduledMaintenanceURL += "-"+submodel;
            }
            scheduledMaintenanceURL += "/listServices.htm";

            window.location = scheduledMaintenanceURL;
        },
```

Comment: Show us some code with your problem

Comment: But we need to see the code .. people cannot understand the whole thing theoritically..

Comment: Post your code, so we can understand what's the exact issue you're facing.

Comment: Please add code here. so easy to find out issue as per your requirement, it not a big deal.

Comment: I added the whole function right there....

Comment: Add in your question instead of the comment.

Comment: Any one got solution???

Comment: Finally i found myself !!!Guys thanks for your concern......